# Foreign key backward navigation in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

For this example:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name='entries')
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    n_comments = models.IntegerField()
    n_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline
```

So, how to find all Blogs with its Entries?

I want to do something like this

```
q = Blog.objects.all().entries.filter(...)
```

But it gave me an error. So does Django only supports to use the backward navigation properties for only one object rather than a set of objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you want to filter on the entries of all blogs, and get the blogs that have entries you require:

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__icontains="cats").distinct()
```

There is a one blog to many entries relationship here, but this query works and gives you the blogs that have entries with cats in headlines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all entries associated with each `Blog`, you can do something like:

```
blogs = Blog.objects.all()
for blog in blogs:
    blog.cached_entries = blog.entry_set.all()
```

Although this looks neat, `n + 1` queries will be made -- 1 query for getting all blogs plus n queries for getting each entry associated with the blog.

It is possible to do this in just one query, but you'll have to do more work if you want to segregate entries by blog.

```
blog_with_entries = []
entries = Entry.objects.order_by('blog')
previous_blog = None
acc_entries = [] # accumulate entries of one blog

for entry in entries:
    if previous_blog != entry.blog:
        if previous_blog is not None:
            blog_with_entries.append((previous_blog, acc_entries))
        acc_entries = []
        previous_blog = entry.blog
    acc_entries.append(entry)
blog_with_entries.append((previous_blog, acc_entries))
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

["Lookups that span relationships"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)